# JavaFX 8 - TableView leak (TableMenuButton)

Tags: java, javafx, memory-leaks, tableview

I have a JavaFX TableView which dynamically changes column properties (width, visibility) to implement multiple "custom settings / column presets".

I noticed a massive amount of uncollected memory whenever I change the column settings. Tried to reproduce the situation with plain java code
and was able to do it with the program appended:

**NOTE:** After starting the program everything is fine! Memory is collected as expected. Things seem to go terribly wrong as soon as we click onto the TableMenuButton (the plus sign) on the right of the column header. It grows
endless until OutOfMemoryError.

[image]

```
public class TableViewMenuButtonLeak extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // ** SETUP TABLE **
        final TableView<Record> table = new TableView<>();

        // things go crazy when the table menu button was pressed
        table.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);

        //generate a bunch of columns
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            TableColumn<Record, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("column"+i);
            column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record, String>("column"+i));
            table.getColumns().add(column1);
        }

        // ** CHANGE TABLE SETTINGS FOREVER **
        Runnable r = () -> {
            while(true) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        table.getColumns().stream().forEach((c) -> c.setPrefWidth(Math.random() * 300));
                        table.getColumns().stream().forEach((c) -> c.setVisible(Math.random() > 0.5 ? true : false));
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();


        // ** SHOW STUFF **
        stage.setTitle("!!!! Do click onto the \"TableMenuButton\" on the right side of the table (PLUS sign) !!!");
        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Record {

        private final StringProperty column1;
        private final StringProperty column2;

        public Record(String column1, String column2) {
            this.column1 = new SimpleStringProperty(column1);
            this.column2 = new SimpleStringProperty(column2);
        }

        public String getColumn1() {
            return column1.get();
        }

        public StringProperty column1Property() {
            return column1;
        }

        public String getColumn2() {
            return column2.get();
        }

        public StringProperty column2Property() {
            return column2;
        }
    }
}
```

Analyzing the heapdump reveals that there are thousands of 
"StackPane"'s, "ContextMenuContent$MenuLabel"s and "ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer" instances.

**My Questions are:**

- Is this a known bug? (at least i did not find a leak description
  which fits to this but of course i could missed it)
- Do you experience the same behaviour?
- Does anybody know a workarround for this issue?

I tested this with JDK 1_8_(60/91/102). All VMs showed the same behaviour!